# Extract string before certain last character

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following Pandas Dataframe:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| AT_A | 1 |
| AT_B | 2 |
| AOS_PAR_F | 3 |
| AOS_ROOT_LE_B | 4 |

I want to create a new column which would hold the string from column "Name" which is before the last "_" character and remove it from the original column.

So the desired output would be:

| Name | ID | Name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | AT |
| B | 2 | AT |
| F | 3 | AOS_PAR |
| B | 4 | AOS_ROOT_LE |

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? - Search for split strings in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a right split ([`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html)):

```
df[['Name_2', 'Name']] = df['Name'].str.rsplit('_', 1, expand=True)
```

Variant with a regex:

```
df[['Name_2', 'Name']] = df['Name'].str.extract(r'(.*)_([^_]+)$')
```

output:

```
  Name  ID       Name_2
0    A   1           AT
1    B   2           AT
2    F   3      AOS_PAR
3    B   4  AOS_ROOT_LE
```